# Python: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python

My code is still unfinished. I am trying to get letter grades based off number grades from a file and then write to a new file. I still think I do not understand functions properly and how I call them in main.

I think I understand that numeric_grade is not reading as an integer. But I am unsure where to use 'int' in my code:

```
# Get letter grade for students, undergrad and grad, and catch invalid number grades an invalid categories.
    def get_letter_grade(numeric_grade, student_type):

        # Catch errors for invalid numbers for grades.
        while (numeric_grade < 0) or (numeric_grade > 100):
            # Display error message for invalid numbers.
            print('Error occurred while determining letter grade. Aborting. ')

        # Student number grade if GRAD student:
        if numeric_grade >= 95 and student_type == 'GRAD':
            letter_grade = 'H'
            return letter_grade
        elif (numeric_grade >= 80) and (numeric_grade < 95) and student_type == 'GRAD':
            letter_grade = 'P'
            return letter_grade
        elif (numeric_grade >= 70) and (numeric_grade < 80) and student_type == 'GRAD':
            letter_grade = 'L'
            return letter_grade
        elif (numeric_grade >= 0) and (numeric_grade < 70) and student_type == 'GRAD':
            letter_grade = 'F'
            return letter_grade

        # Student number grade if UNDERGRAD student:
        elif numeric_grade >= 90 and student_type == 'UNDERGRAD':
            letter_grade = 'A'
            return letter_grade
        elif (numeric_grade >= 80) and (numeric_grade < 90) and student_type == 'UNDERGRAD':
            letter_grade = 'B'
            return letter_grade
        elif (numeric_grade >= 70) and (numeric_grade < 80) and student_type == 'UNDERGRAD':
            letter_grade = 'C'
            return letter_grade
        elif (numeric_grade >= 60) and (numeric_grade < 70) and student_type == 'UNDERGRAD':
            letter_grade = 'D'
            return letter_grade
        elif (numeric_grade >= 0) and (numeric_grade < 60) and student_type == 'UNDERGRAD':
            letter_grade = 'F'
            return letter_grade


    # Run main program.
    def main():
        # Prompt the user to enter the name of the input file.
        in_filename = input('Please enter the name of the input data file: ')

        # Open input file in read mode.
        try:
            in_file = open(in_filename, 'r')

        # Make sure that the file exists and ask the user to re-enter a filename if needed.
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(in_filename, ' could not be opened. Please restart.')

        # Prompt the user to enter the name of an output file.
        out_filename = input('Please enter the name of the output data file: ')
        # The output file should be erased/overwritten if an old one with the same name exists.
        out_file = open(out_filename, 'w')

        # Prime the loop by reading first record (first 3 lines).
        category = in_file.readline()
        student_name = in_file.readline()
        num_grade = in_file.readline()

        # Write first record to output file.
        out_file.write(category)
        out_file.write(student_name)
        out_file.write(num_grade)

        # Read input file one line at a time:
        while category != '' and student_name != '' and num_grade != '':
            # Read input line for student category.
            category = in_file.readline()
            # Read input line for student name.
            student_name = in_file.readline()
            # Read input line for grade.
            num_grade = in_file.readline()

            # Remove the newlines.
            category = category.rstrip('\n')
            student_name = student_name.rstrip('\n')
            num_grade = num_grade.rstrip('\n')

            # Write output file.
            out_file.write(str(category + '\n'))
            out_file.write(str(student_name + '\n'))
            out_file.write(str(num_grade + '\n'))

        # Assign grades as appropriate for type of student (GRAD vs UNDERGRAD).
        letter_grade = get_letter_grade(num_grade, category)
        while letter_grade != '':
            out_file.write(letter_grade)
            letter_grade = get_letter_grade(num_grade, category)

        in_file.close()
        out_file.close()


    main()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure about the reliability of your datatype, I would convert the input to a float when you call the function like;

```
letter_grade = get_letter_grade(num_grade=float(num_grade), category=category)
```

This will transfer `num_grade` into a number if it is a string. If it is already a number then there is still no harm in doing this.

Also, if you want another way to read in files on the command line then I would recommend using `sys` since this will let you read everything in as one (so you can page-up and repeat the function easily without re-typing) and also tab-complete to ensure files exist. Here is an example;

```
import sys

def main(input_file, output_file):
   ... main code goes here


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
```

Here sys.argv gets what you type into the command line (after the first argument which is the function) and inserts it as arguments into your function.

Therefore you can use it by typing
`python file_name.py <input_file_path/in_filename > <output_filepath/in_filename >` into your terminal

and it will execute `main(input_file=input_file_path, output_file=output_filepath)`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that you need to understand here:

1. Whenever you read something from file/input or any other text form **it is read as a string.** This behaviour cannot be changed, simply because you can read almost anything from the string and this is not interpeted in any way as number/list/whatever.
2. Whenever you know that something you read **should be** number/list/whatever, you can cast it to proper type later in code. Definitely you should cast it before you use its numeric property (like adding numbers or some calculations).

So the pattern is usually:

1. Read something as string
2. Do some string processing (in your case rstrip)
3. Cast to the number/object/list/whatever you need (in your case integer representing grade)
4. Use it as a variable of certain type.

Summing up, ideal place to cast your variable would be after this line:

```
num_grade = num_grade.rstrip('\n') ,
```

but before passing it to the function get_letter_grade.